# Python - multiplication based on row values

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a data frame and three variables x,y,z.

```
x = 10, y = 20, z = 30

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c'],
                   'B':[6,7,8]})
```

Here is what I want to do:

Create a new column 'C':

```
If df['A'] == 'a', df['C'] = df['B']*x
If df['A'] == 'b', df['C'] = df['B']*y
If df['A'] == 'c', df['C'] = df['B']*z
```

Any quick ways to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a dictionary mapping the column A value to the multiplication value, then use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) on column A and multiply it against column B:

```
mul_map = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}
df['C'] = df['B'] * df['A'].map(mul_map)
```

The resulting output:

```
   A  B    C
0  a  6   60
1  b  7  140
2  c  8  240
```

Comment: I'd actually be interested in seeing a time comparison for these two approaches. My intuition is that `.map` is slow, if it is anything like `.apply`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It's probably slower than the `np.where` solution, but more readable once the number of items you're mapping increases (vs. say a 10x nested `np.where`).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's much faster than apply if you are not using a custom function.

Comment: @ayhan what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it accepts a function so you can do things like `ser.map(lambda x: ...)`  and it is slow in that case. But if you pass a Series or a dict for a lookup, it is very fast (much faster than applying a row by row lookup).

Comment: @ayhan Ah, so it's fast with a series or dict but slow with a callable. Got it. Makes sense. Good to know!

Comment: At this moment running time is not a concern, answer accepted!

Comment: Gratz on 10,000

Answer (score 3):

You can use np.where

```
df['C'] = np.where(df.A == 'a', df.B*x, np.where(df.A == 'b', df.B*y, df.B*z))
```

You get

```
    A   B   C
0   a   6   60
1   b   7   140
2   c   8   240
```

Comment: I'm willing to be this is the fastest way!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, both seem to be comparable at the current size

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion something more readable (albeit slower):

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 'a', 'C'] = df['B']*x
df.loc[df['A'] == 'b', 'C'] = df['B']*y
df.loc[df['A'] == 'c', 'C'] = df['B']*z
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution so far.

```
#use apply to compare df.A with a,b,c and choose x,y or z.
df.apply(lambda r: r.B*[x,y,z][['a','b','c'].index(r.A)], axis=1)
Out[438]: 
0     60
1    140
2    240
dtype: int64
```

**Speed Test**

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda r: r.B*[x,y,z][['a','b','c'].index(r.A)], axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 580 µs per loop

%timeit np.where(df.A == 'a', df.B*x, np.where(df.A == 'b', df.B*y, df.B*z))
1000 loops, best of 3: 932 µs per loop

%timeit df['B'] * df['A'].map(mul_map)
1000 loops, best of 3: 686 µs per loop
```